# Intro to PDEs: $\Delta$ use in the maximum principle proof for Laplace's Equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am in a class called Intro to Partial Differential Equations (I am an undergrad student and all of this is very new to me, so please be patient with me and what may appear to be a silly question). I have been examining the proof of the Maximum Principle for Laplace's Equation (in 2D). I am having trouble understanding the use of the delta symbol in the following case:

Let $v(x,y)=u(x,y)+\epsilon (x^2+y^2)$.

Then $\Delta v = \Delta u + \epsilon \Delta (x^2+y^2) = 0 + 4\epsilon$.

What is the $\Delta$ operation doing here? Why does $\epsilon \Delta (x^2+y^2)=4\epsilon$? In particular, where does the 4 come from? Why does $\Delta (x^2+y^2) = 4$? Clearly, this has something to do with the Laplacian, but I don't see how it works. I would like to see the work omitted from the statement (even if you think it's silly, it would be very helpful to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplace Operator is defined as $\Delta u(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,y) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}u(x,y)$. Hence you get
$$ \Delta(x^2+y^2) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(x^2+y^2) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}(x^2+y^2) = 2 + 2 = 4.$$
Hope you got it :)

Comment: Thanks! It really helped to see it written out like that.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$$

is the Laplacian. Now try to calculate

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right)(x^2+ y^2).$$